# Make ERB.run quiet

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I'm using ERB inside a Rails app to render an ERB template, something like...

```
T = ERB.new(...)
result = T.run(....)
```

However I noticed in my terminal that ERB is dumping the transformation (from erb template to filled-in text) to the terminal. How can I make ERB be quiet?

Comment: Why are you rendering a template this way?

Comment: I am generating HTML files on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with this:

```
T = ERB.new(...)
file = open('some-new-file.html','w')
file.write T.result(binding) # where binding is the thing that has the data
```